# Using `SpotifyClientCredentials` to list recent tracks

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, spotify, credentials, spotipy

I'm trying to write a bot (AWS Lambda function) to list the tracks I listened to while doing my various Strava activities. I get a start time for each activity once it's posted to Strava, and so I'm trying to use the `client_id` and `client_secret` set up with Spotify Developers to authenticate (server-to-server) with the `SpotifyClientCredentials` as the `auth_manager` in the client Spotipy initialization to then get the [current_user_recently_played](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.1/#spotipy.client.Spotify.current_user_recently_played) but am hitting snags around `scope` and OAuth2.

- Using `SpotifyClientCredentials` with just `client_id` and `client_secret`, I get `Only valid bearer authentication supported, reason: None`
- Using `get_access_token()` on the `SpotifyClientCredentials` obj and then using the `access_token` as the `auth` in the `Spotify` initialization, I get `Insufficient client scope, reason: None`
- When I (stupidly) try to use `SpotifyOAuth` as the `auth_manager`, setting the `client_id`, `client_secret`, `redirect_url` and `scope="user-read-recently-played"`, I get `spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: error: invalid_request, error_description: code must be supplied`.

Could someone tell me if this is even possible in a headless/server-to-server scenario?

Comment: *"The Client Credentials flow is used in server-to-server authentication. Since this flow does not include authorization, only endpoints **that do not access user information** can be accessed."*